# Titanium: Clarity Missing toImage() Conversion (Android & ios)

Tags: android, ios, image, titanium

I develop Android and iOS apps using Titanium Appcelerator. I have converted my view to an image using `toImage()` method, but viewing the image, it looks a little fuzzy, and unclear. 
What should I do to get a better image quality?

```
if (Ti.Platform.osname == "android") {
    var _pic = myView.toImage().media;
} else {
    var _pic = myView.toImage();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

On iOS devices, the toImage method recieves an extra parameter (second parameter - first one is a callback) to honorScaleFactor.

For more info: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-method-toImage